# Product of two polynomials is a polynomial with coefficients being zero for certain degrees

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Let $k$ be a field and let $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be an infinite subset. Let $f \in k[t]$ be a polynomial. Show that there exists a polynomial $g \in k[t]$ such that $f(t)g(t) = \sum_{i \geq 0}a_it^i$, where $a_i = 0$ for every $i \notin S$.

Can we consider the quotient $\frac{k[t]
}{(f)}$? Then its dimension is equal to $deg(f)=d$(say). Then the set $\{x^k\mid k\in S\}$ is linearly dependent and hence we will get some finite subset $S'\subseteq S$ such that
$$ \sum_{i \in S'}\overline{a_it^i}=0.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 5):

I would send the polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ to its companion matrix $C_f\in M_n(k)$.

Its minimal polynomial is $f$.

What we want is some $s_j\in S,a_j\in k$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^J a_j C_f^{s_j} = 0$,

which will give that $f$ divides $\sum_{j=1}^J a_j t^{s_j}$.

To construct some $s_j,a_j$ it suffices to use that $M_n(k)$ is a $n^2$-dimensional $k$-vector space, so for any $s_1,\ldots,s_{n^2+1}\in S$ the set $C_f^{s_1},\ldots,C_f^{s_{n^2+1}}$ is $k$-linearly dependent, ie. there are some $a_j\in k$ not all zero such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n^2+1} a_j C_f^{s_j} = 0$.